# Serialize and deserialize a collection to JSON Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, serialization

I've searched a lot, but cannot find a working solution. Most likely because I'm pretty new to Delphi (and coming from C#).

I have a unit with the following class declaration:

```
TReplaceField = class
public
  Key: string;
  Value: string;
  constructor Create; overload;
  constructor Create(strKey, strValue: string); overload;
end;
```

Class can also be record, like suggested in the comment.

I want to create a collection of it, be it an array, `TList<T>`, or whatever suits best in this case, and then serialize it to JSON (to store it) and later deserialze it to loop over the fields.

I've found `REST.JSON` and `TJson.ObjectToJsonString()`, which works good for 1 object.

But if I pass an `array of TReplaceField`, it gives me a compile error:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'TObject' and 'Dynamic array'

When I use a `TList` at runtime, I get a different error:

> type tkPointer is not currently supported

In C#, all of this is pretty easy, like a few lines of code.  I'm pretty stuck on how to do it in Delphi (besides creating JSON by hand via string concatenation).

**UPDATE:**
With the tips from David, I've got the serialization working. Also deserialization of one object works, but not deserialization of a collection.

My class now looks like this:

```
TReplaceField = class
private
  FKey      : string;
  FValue    : string;
published
  property Key : string read FKey write FKey;
  property Value : string read FValue write FValue;
public
  constructor Create; overload;
  constructor Create(strKey, strValue: string); overload;
end;
```

- Serialize one object: `mmoJson.Lines.Text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Field);` OK
- Deserialize one object: `JsonToObject<TReplaceField>(mmoJson.Lines.Text);` OK
- Serialize collection: `mmoJson.Lines.Text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(FieldList);` OK
- Deserialize collection: `JsonToObject<TReplaceField>(mmoJson.Lines.Text);` FAIL, message:

  > EConversionError with message 'Internal: Cannot instantiate type System.Generics.Collections.TList<uReplaceField.TReplaceFieldRec>'

Using a record instead of class for `ReplaceField` gives the same results.

Almost there.  What am I missing to get it fully working?

Comment: Why are you using `TList` rather than the generic `TList<T>` from `Generics.Collections`? Having said that, trying to serialize collections of classes using just RTTI is an area where there is much scope for shabby JSON production, and Delphi doesn't have a great track record. This particular class would surely be better as a simple record, and they tend to serialize more robustly.

Comment: Didn't know about the TList<T> in Delphi. I'm used to generics from C#, so wouldn't be a problem to use generics. Thanks for noticing.
That's also why I started about colletion, as I'm not sure which type to use (hence the 'whatever suits best')
So you're advicing to use a record instead of class? No problem to use that

Comment: For the very simple type here then a record is probably more appropriate. It's just a compound type with a couple of fields. Were it to get loads more complex then you might consider a class. Still `TList<T>` or `TObjectList<T>` are what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm able to serialize and deserialize an object now. Also serialization of `TList<T>` also works, but now the deserialization...
I will update my post with the code I have atm

Comment: I've made [jsondoc](https://github.com/stijnsanders/jsonDoc#jsondoc) to work with variant arrays, but those work in yet another way compared to dynamic arrays and `TList<T>`...

Comment: @StijnSanders thanks for the tip, but at the moment I don't have time to learn yet another type of collection (variant arrays). 
For now I fixed it by using XML, as that's easy to deserialize. If someone knows how to get it working, I hope he/she will share it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
type
 TReplaceCollect = TList<TReplaceField>;
```

Add this after-class declaration.